# How to implement a callback using reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

**I have this constructor in a jar:**

```
public ClientListFragment(String[] values, OnActionListener onActionListener)
{
    this.values = values;
    this.setOnActionListener(onActionListener);
}
```

**This is the implementation of the abstract class OnActionListener:**

```
public abstract class OnActionListener {

    public abstract void onAction(int actonId);
}
```

**In the main project, create an instance of this class, which is in a jar:**

```
 final String libPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapi.jar";
           final File tmpDir = new File(libPath);

           final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(libPath, tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
           final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass("com.api.fragment.ClientListFragment");


//In this constructor, we inform an array of String and not know how to pass the callback of the abstract class
           Constructor constructor = classToLoad.getConstructor(new Class[]{String[].class});

//get a instance
           Object fragmentListClients = constructor.newInstance(items);
```

**My question is: How do I report a callback to a loaded class via reflection in Java? 
Ie how:**

```
onActionListener = new OnActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAction(int actonId) {

            }
        };
```

Comment: Just a thought, but could you have your class (e.g. confirmWithdrawal)  extend some kind of base abstract class that requires each subclass to define its own instance of OnActionListener? So the class itself would handle it, not your loader?

Comment: By report a listener (callback) to the class, do you mean get one from the loaded class? Or add one to the loaded class? Pass one into a method invocation on an instance of the class?

Comment: I want to create an external event, dynamically, which is called from inside the jar. 
But do not know how I can do this with reflection. 
I think this can help me here, I'm trying to understand. 
http://tuhrig.de/implementing-interfaces-and-abstract-classes-on-the-fly/

Comment: called when from inside the jar?  The question sounds to me like how to get a handle to the action handler into the context where it is to be called.  ie: Where and in what context is the handler coming from? and where and in what context do you want to call it?

Comment: It looks like the proxy simply dynamically passes the arguments via it's "invoke" method into a method by name and argument "type" array into a matching method found by reflection on the proxied class. So are you interested in somehow passing the "action listener" representing an instance of the proxy class to something that invokes it? ie: make the proxy representable as an instance of OnActionListener?

Comment: Is the issue that the abstract class for OnActionListener is abstact and an instance can't be created?  

If so then you will have to somehow create a concrete subclass of OnActionListsner using the class loaded from the jar.

Comment: Or is it you want to use the two argument constructor to create the object? you will have to add OnActionListener.class to the argument type array when finding the constructor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    Method onAction = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("onAction", int.class);
    onAction.invoke(fragmentListClients, 1);
```

Where `fragmentListClients` is the target object `1` is your actionId. You're using reflection to get a reference to the Method and invoking it.

You'd probably be better off creating an interface and using inheritance to implement and call your `onAction` method as that gets you type safety and avoids reflection for the method call which can be inefficient.

Comment: Hi @Cícero Moura if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligati

Comment: @Baldy to register for call back you must use Dynamic proxies, I don't no why Cícero Moura accepted this answer. This answer mislead me and I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out how you are able to do it. Finally I came across this : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

You must use Dynamic proxies to implement interfaces at run-time
Please go through this link for more Info.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html